# Using datatable to search on a hidden nested table with different count of columns

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have a functioning html table that works like so:

- Main table is generated with parent level data
- Child level rows are generated (these have details associated with parent row)
- Child rows are in a nested table that is hidden from view until the parent level hyperlink is clicked
- Clicking creates a dropdown effect with detail rows

THis works, but when I try to implement DataTables, I get an error on establishing the cell index:

`jquery.dataTables.min.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '_DT_CellIndex')`

I can get datatables to work fine when I strip out the nested table, but I need datatables working so that it can search on ALL data, whether parent or child rows. I know the issue is that the number of columns in the nested table are different than the parent one, but I've yet to find a solution that can actually achieve what I want which is having the toggle functionality for child rows but having ALL data searchable by datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var dt = $('#nestedTable').DataTable({
           "pageLength": 50,
           "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,-1],[10,25,50,'All']],
           dom: 'Bflrtip',
           // 'scrollX': true,
           buttons: [
               'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
           ]
        });
    });

    function toggleDetails(anchor) {
    var detailTableRow = anchor.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling;
    if (detailTableRow.classList.contains("details")) {
        if (detailTableRow.style.display === "none") {
            detailTableRow.style.display = "table-row";
        } else {
            detailTableRow.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<html>
<body>
<table id="nestedTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Record Number</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
            <th>Date Printed</th>
            <th>Date Completed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="colorize parent" style="background-color: #FEEBA1;">
            <td><a onclick="toggleDetails(this)">123456789</a></td>
            <td>2023-04-01</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="details" style="display: none">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover" style="background-color:#F9F9F9">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product ID</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Catgegory</th>
                            <th>Number</th>
                            <th>User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ABCD1234</td>
                            <td>Type 1</td>
                            <td>Catgegory A 1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>John Smith</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EFGH5678</td>
                            <td>Type 2</td>
                            <td>Catgegory B 2</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Jane Doe</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="colorize parent">
            <td><a onclick="toggleDetails(this)">987654321</a></td>
            <td>2023-03-31</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
            <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="details" style="display: none">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover" style="background-color:#F9F9F9">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product ID</th>
                            <th>Frame</th>
                            <th>Catgegory</th>
                            <th>Number</th>
                            <th>User</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IJKL9012</td>
                            <td>Frame 3</td>
                            <td>Catgegory C 3</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Bob Johnson</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MNOP3456</td>
                            <td>Frame 4</td>
                            <td>Catgegory D 4</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Samantha Lee</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>QRST7890</td>
                            <td>Frame 5</td>
                            <td>Catgegory E 5</td>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Chris Williams</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For a similar scenario (but using [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) approach), I added all the child data to a hidden column in the parent table, where it can be searched using the standard global search input. I do not need to search the child table data directly.

Comment: The Stack Snippet throws an error when it runs, by the way.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check into that solution